# Excel : table columns reference to a cell

Tags: excel, data-structures, excel-formula, reference, multiple-columns

is there any way to reference in this formula `=SUM(Sales[Jan])`, using as a value between brackets a cell value?

What I am trying to achieve is giving this formula `=SUM(Sales[a1])` where the value of the cell `A1 = Jan`.

I would like to do something similar in the flooring formula

```
index(Sales;SECUENCE(ROWS(SALES));{1\3\5})
```

And I would like to do something like:

```
index(Sales;SECUENCE(ROWS(SALES));{A1})
```

where A1 value = 1/3/5

Answer (score 0):

You need `INDIRECT()` function.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Table1["&A1&"]"))
```

Alternatively you can use `SUMPRODUCT()` like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table1*(--(Table1[#Headers]=A1)))
```

[image]